# “initMboxBlock: init mbox zaps failed” when using pigpio library in a daemon using node.js

Tags: power, node.js, pigpio, systemd, javascript

I am writing a daemon using node.js, running under systemd and it will [monitor the status of the power supply voltage on a raspberry pi 2 B](https://github.com/saraf/raspi2-power-monitor).

I am using the [node.js wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pigpio) to the pigpio library

The code I started with was as follows:

```
var Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio,
gpio;

gpio = new Gpio(35);

const checkIntervalDuringBrownout   = 5000;
const checkIntervalDuringGoodSupply = 100;
var timer = 100;

function startTimer() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var brownoutState = isUnderVoltage();

    if(brownoutState) {
      console.log("Brownout - telling the syslog ...");
      console.log("Brownout ... Power Supply Voltage went below 4.63 V");
      timer = checkIntervalDuringBrownout;
    }
    else {
      timer = checkIntervalDuringGoodSupply;
   }
    startTimer();
  }, timer);
}

function isUnderVoltage() {
  var ledStatus = gpio.digitalRead(); 
  if(ledStatus === 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  else if (ledStatus === 0) {
    //console.log("brownout");
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    console.log("We got neither a 1 or a 0: ", ledStatus);
  }
}

startTimer();
```

was getting mysterious error messages in the syslog:

```
Aug  2 00:22:10 chintu systemd[1]: Started Brownout Monitor and Logger written using node.js.
Aug  2 00:22:11 chintu brownout-monitor[5203]: 2017-08-02 00:22:11 initMboxBlock: init mbox zaps failed
Aug  2 00:22:11 chintu brownout-monitor[5203]: /home/pi/sandbox/raspi2-power-monitor/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:11
Aug  2 00:22:11 chintu brownout-monitor[5203]: pigpio.gpioInitialise();
Aug  2 00:22:11 chintu brownout-monitor[5203]: ^
Aug  2 00:22:11 chintu brownout-monitor[5203]: Error: pigpio error -1 in gpioInitialise
Aug  2 00:22:11 chintu brownout-monitor[5203]: at Error (native)
Aug  2 00:22:11 chintu brownout-monitor[5203]: at initializePigpio (/home/pi/sandbox/raspi2-power-monitor/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:11:12)
Aug  2 00:22:11 chintu brownout-monitor[5203]: at new Gpio (/home/pi/sandbox/raspi2-power-monitor/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:25:3)
```

and

```
Aug  2 00:17:11 chintu systemd[1]: Starting Brownout Monitor and Logger written using node.js...
Aug  2 00:17:11 chintu systemd[1]: Started Brownout Monitor and Logger written using node.js.
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: 2017-08-02 00:17:12 initInitialise: Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: /home/pi/sandbox/raspi2-power-monitor/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:11
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: pigpio.gpioInitialise();
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: ^
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: Error: pigpio error -1 in gpioInitialise
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: at Error (native)
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: at initializePigpio (/home/pi/sandbox/raspi2-power-monitor/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:11:12)
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: at new Gpio (/home/pi/sandbox/raspi2-power-monitor/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:25:3)
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/sandbox/raspi2-power-monitor/index.js:7:8)
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu brownout-monitor[4555]: at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu systemd[1]: brownout-monitor.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  2 00:17:12 chintu systemd[1]: Unit brownout-monitor.service entered failed state.
```

Looking up these errors led me to a page where the solution said -

> I'll have to check the code but off the top of my head the most likely
>   is that the GPU (which allocates mbox DMA memory) has no spare memory.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that fixed the errors was:

Handling the signals that systemd sends to the node process and ensuring that the pigpio library does a clean termination using the `pigpio.terminate()` call in the handler.

```
var pigpio = require('pigpio');
var Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio,
    gpio;

//....

process.on('SIGHUP', shutdown);
process.on('SIGINT', shutdown);
process.on('SIGCONT', shutdown);
process.on('SIGTERM', shutdown);

function shutdown() {
  pigpio.terminate();
  clearInterval(timerVar);
  console.log('raspi2-brownout-watcher must exit, performed cleanup.');
  process.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.